# not able to display user location on android app the first time its installed(android studio)

Tags: android

I want my app to display user's location...and I have applied all the required methods and it is working as well displaying user's location but not at the first time when I install the app. The **getDeviceLocation method is not executed the first time but everytime after that**. How should I modify my code to make the address dislayed and loaded to the database right from the first time.

Comment: post your code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing getDeviceLocation method you have check for location permission.
and check is Provider is enabled or not . if not request for Provider enable and call 
getDeviceLocation method in onrequestpermissionsresult then you will get the location
on first time also

Comment: Ohh okay I did not call getDeviceLocation in onRequestPermissionsResult, rather I have called it in getLocationPermission. Thanks a lot!